# Return multiple rows with ajax from database - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

View: Trying to retrieve items based on length, width and height.

```
<form method="post" action="">

  <label for="title">L</label>
  <input type="text" name="length" id="length" value="" />
</br>
  <label for="title">W</label>
  <input type="text" name="width" id="width" value="" />
</br>
  <label for="title">H</label>
  <input type="text" name="height" id="height" value="" />

  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

js file:

```
$("#submit").click(function (e) {
event.preventDefault();

    var length = $('#length').val();
    var width = $('#width').val();
    var height = $('#height').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://domain.com/index.php/welcome/get_items",
        data: {
            length: length, width: width, height: height
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('div#cont').text(data.content);
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('Failed!')
    });

});
```

Controller: I m not sure how to structure this. If only one value is typed in, it should look for that, if two it should match the row that has the two dimensions, and the same if all three are present. Do I check and see which value is given and create multiple model functions?

I also seem to have a problem with the foreach statement below. It won't return multiple rows.

```
public function get_items()
{
        $this->load->model('home_model');

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('length', 'Length', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('width', 'Width', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('height', 'Height', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

            $length = $_GET['length'];
            $width = $_GET['width'];
            $height = $_GET['height'];

            $one_exp = $this->home_model->one_exp($length, $width, $height);

        if($one_exp != false){
                //$html = '<ul>';
                foreach($one_exp as $exp) {
                        $html = $exp->width . $exp->color . $exp->filename;
                }
                //$html .= '</ul>';
                $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $html);
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($result);
                exit();
        }else{
                $result = array('status' => 'no', 'content' => 'nothing here');
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($result);
                exit();
        }

}
```

Model: The below function is just for testing.

```
function one_exp($length, $width, $height) {
       $query_str = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE length =? || width=? || height=?";
       $query = $this->db->query($query_str, array($length, $width, $height));

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $item) {
            $data[] = $item;
        }
            return $data;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
}
```

*** Edit

```
function one_exp($length, $width, $height) {
       //$query_str = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE length =? || width=? || height=?";
$query_str = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE ";

$query_and=array();

  if( !empty($length)){
      $query_and[]= ' length =?';
  }
  if( !empty($width)){
      $query_and[]=  ' width=?';
  }
  if( !empty($height)){
       $query_and[]=  ' height=?';
   }

$query_str .= implode(' AND ', $query_and);

    $query = $this->db->query($query_str, array($length, $width, $height));

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $item) {
            $data[] = $item;
        }
            return $data;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Response

```
Array
(
[0] =>  width=?
[1] =>  height=?
)
string(7) "Width50"
string(8) "Height60"
SELECT * FROM files WHERE width=''AND height='50'{"status":"no","content":"nothing here"}
```

Comment: Is my answer helpful ???

Comment: You don't need `status: ok/no`. the `200 OK` HTTP status code of the response is sufficient - in case there are no records to display, just return `[]`.

Comment: @moonwave99 how would I check for that? can you show me an example?

Comment: [Set http response code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) // [first google result for REST status codes](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the query goes you can create the query string based on the arguments , something like:

```
function one_exp($length, $width, $height) {
    $query_str = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE ";

    $query_and=array();
      if( !empty($length)){
          $query_and[]= ' length =?';
      }
      if( !empty($width)){
          $query_and[]=  ' width=?';
      }
      if( !empty($height)){
           $query_and[]=  ' height=?';
       }
    $query_str .= implode(' AND ', $query_and);
    /* do query */

}
```

Just make sure at least one of the arguments has a valid value

Comment: hi. thank you for your help. I tried it(see my edit please), but it only works if length is not empty. If I add more arguments, it returns false ... any idea why? another thing ... how do I debug variables from the model? how would I var_dump or print_r $query_and?

Comment: I suggest you echo `$query_str` and test that in your mysql GUI (ie phpMyAdmin). Can see output in browser console by inspecting request itself and copy response body

Comment: can also use `echo $this->db->last_query()` after any db query to see what query string was

Comment: wow ... you just helped me so much. I had no idea how to see queries. thank you so much! However there is still something weird going on ... I can't seem to figure out. If I add a length, width, and height it works. If I add length and height, the height argument is missing. Same if I add width and height.

Comment: weird ... i ll keep trying.

Comment: I just added a response to my question. The variables are set, but aren't being set in the query. If you can take a look it would help a lot. Thanks

Comment: find out what the values of each are then in the php...might need something more than test for `!empty`. Can always dump $_GET

Comment: from what I see, if i have length=40 width=nothing height=60, length is being passed to the first variable in the query and nothing is wbeing passed to the second which is supppose to be the height value. What can I set the variable to if it is empty and not affect the query?

Comment: depends what php is translating `nothing` as, does it consider it `empty` or not. Also try adding `isset` in tests

Comment: possible quick fix...`$height = $_GET['height'] || '';`

Comment: where would that go? in the controller?

Comment: yes...where you already have `$height=`...you just need to learn a little more about debugging your php...can open controler in browser and output whatever you want in page ...just add query strings to url

Comment: let me know what you find out

Comment: Only thing I can think of. Not sure if it's possible. `$query = $this->db->query($query_str, array( implode('$', $query_str ));` and of course clean the `=?` and the space. Since the array elements are the only arguments passed, why not use them to set the query array too? I m not sure how to do that ... tried with `str_replace` but no luck. What do you think? Can it be done?

Comment: oooo yes...forgot the array argument for data in `query` needs to be right. Similar to `$query_and=array()` ...try `$query_data=array()` and then do things like `if( !empty($length)){ $query_data[]=$lenght`..then `db->query($query_str,$query_data)`

Comment: nice! it seems to work. i ll do a few more tests tomorrow then add the correct code to my question.4:30 am now :D

Comment: great..sorry forgot about looking at the data array... a lot easier when working with own live code

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in this section

```
foreach($one_exp as $exp) {
    $html = $exp->width . $exp->color . $exp->filename;
}
```

The varriable `$html` is reinitialized each time

So make a update

```
foreach($one_exp as $exp) {
    $html .= $exp->width . $exp->color . $exp->filename."<br>";
}
```